# Basic Auth is not working within my server, but works from my computer

Tags: wget, basic-authentication, portforwarding

I'm having a problem while trying to connect to my CCTV from my server to retrieve pictures of cameras.

There's no "science" on it, you just do an http request with Basic Auth to an URL an get the image, like this:

```
wget http://username:password@ipaddress:port/m/camera.jpg
```

When I run this command on my terminals computer, it works like a charm, I get the JPG image, but when I do it on my server I get this log:

```
Connecting to ipaddress:port... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
Reusing existing connection to ipaddress:port.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
Authorization failed.
```

The port for the connection is `5555`

My server firewall has the port 5555 for in/out connections enabled, so I don't think my server is blocking it.

Comment: Are you sure that there's no "science" at play, like your camera only accepting logins from LAN IPs?

Comment: @zb226 Nope, is not that, I've been able to do it remotely, from outside my LAN network.

Comment: @CarlosC have you ever found an answer ?